# describe the speed file for two-cores host

Tags: xml, simgrid

I am using SimGrid to simulate a network of connected hosts. I described the technical specifications of each host using the platform file (XML File). Each host also has a ***speed_file*** but one of the host has two cores and I can't find a way to describe the ***speed_file*** for more than one-core host.
The following describes the speed file (availability) of one core host:

```
0 1.0
11 0.5
20 0.9
LOOPAFTER 1
```

What would the ***speed_file*** be like for a two-core host?

Comment: Given the lack of response and after a long experience with SimGrid, I would say that the speed_files applies to both cores. You can't actually have a multi-core CPU and each core behaves differently based on its speed